# I am getting SSL Error, while trying to communicate with the server through my iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ssl

I am getting an error "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made".

Same code is working fine while communicating with another server, i want to make sure whether the issue is due the certificate on server.

Comment: look into the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge method of protocol..

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the server that you are hitting is **HTTPS** server. It requires an SSL check.

Answer (score 1):

please check the url of the server you are communicating with , it must be using HTTPS , try using the service with HTTP.

Comment: I am trying to connect with both servers using SSL itself, i am aware of it,i have written code to support SSL, but its not working with one of the server,while it is working fine with others.